# Alka Seltzer Model: formulas/models requested

Tags: thermodynamics, classical-mechanics

This evening I became fascinated with how my Alka Seltzer tablet disintegrates over time within a small portion of Diet Lipton Citrus Ice Tea. I used a nearly frozen cup; tall, as one might request in a middle-class restaurant.

It is interesting to notice that the Alka Seltzer tablet attempts to float to the top of the glass; but it just cant quite make it, e.g., it keeps bobbing up and down and finally it becomes complete residue.

What are the formulas for this, completely? What might the mathematical model look like from start to finish? My first identifications include, but certainly not limited to: measuring the cup, the milligrams deposited into the cup and of course a the makings of a typical tablet of Alka Seltzer excluding room temperature?

Comment: Honestly, this seems like a really vague question, and also one that you haven't put much effort into yourself.

Comment: The problem isn't just the vagueness of the question. I get the feeling that you don't understand what a mathematical model is. If someone developed a model and presented it, what would you learn from it? What aspects of this would you like to see modeled?

Comment: Might [chemistry.se] be better suited for this question?

Comment: @-4 ...This is a classical physical phenomena. Please respect that.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the Alka Seltzer is an effervescent kind of tablet.
When it is immersed in water, gas bubbles form on the tablet surface and surface tension effects prevent the bubbles from separating them from the tablet surface. By this effect the global density of the system tablet plus bubbles is going down overtime, until the global density approaches the density of water. At that point, the tablet + bubbles start to float and moving upwards to the water/air interface. At that interface, the tablet looses some of the bubbles as they explode, what makes the global density go up again (exceeding the density of water). As a consequence, the tablet sinks again and the process starts all-over. What you typically observe is that, after a few cycles, the tablet has grown so thin that when the tablet reaches the air/water interface, enough bubbles keep sticking to the tablet (on the bottom side for example) to prevent that the global density gets higher than that of water again. As a consequence, the tablet will stay at the interface air/water until it is completely dissolved.
So, the key parameters to take into account when modeling are 1. the surface area of the tablet, 2. the initial mass of the tablet, 3. the volume of gas produced per area of tablet surface per second when immersed in water and the mass-loss per area of tablet surface per second when immersed in water.