# Falling then rising of an effervescent tablet dropped into a glass of water

Tags: fluid-dynamics

If you drop an effervescent tablet into a glass of water. The tablet first sinks to the base of the glass and effervesces energetically - producing a rising column of bubbles, i.e. a bubble plume - as it dissolves. Later the partially dissolved tablet (of reduced mass compared with the original tablet) rises to the surface of the glass on a cushion of bubbles. 
What is(are) the reason(s) for this phenomenon?

Comment: Duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/196141/

Answer (score 1):

When you first drop it in, it is denser than water and so it sinks. As it reacts with water, gas bubbles are released and the tablet begins to dissolve and lose mass. Some gas bubbles get trapped in the nooks and crannies of the tablet and don't rise to the top.

Eventually, enough of these bubbles get trapped and enough of the mass of the tablet has dissolved that now the buoyant forces of the trapped bubbles is more than the gravitational force pulling the tablet down. The bubbles then start to lift the tablet up until it floats to the surface.

This has other, practical effects. For instance, you can [raise a sunken ship](http://mythbusters.wikia.com/wiki/Ping_Pong_Salvage_Myth) with ping-pong balls.

Answer (score -3):

The tablet first sinks into water, then air trapped in the tablet comes out rapidly . The effervescence is very high and buoyant force of water makes the tablet float.